# How to add new question to chatbot using Django and chatterbot from front end?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, chatbot, chatterbot

A final year B.E project, chatbot for farmer.

We have used chatterbot and Django for our project.
Have admin and farmer modules.
Now admin has permission to add new question.
How to add the new question to the chatbot using a Django form from front-end?

Comment: Hi. Could you include the relevant code of your project to the question. This will give you more chance of getting a useful response that doesn't need clarifications.

Comment: This question is unclear. Please provide relevant details.
Also, visit the help center to know this site better https://stackoverflow.com/help